# wait until no text in a box / boxes

Tags: java, selenium, wait

I am writing in java a method using selenium that will clear a form entry, that is, several boxes may have text in them.  My method will click a "clear search form" and then wait for all the boxes to be clear.  I tried the following:

```html
  WebDriverWait wt = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
  click("Clear Search Form", clearSearchForm);
  for (int ind = 0; ind < boxes.size(); ind++) {
   wt.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementValue(boxes.get(ind), ""));
  }
```

however, it looks like the Expected Conditions waits for the text to contain "" rather than to equal "", so any text will contain "".  I forgot to put in the clearSearchForm click, and the method succeeded anyway even though the text boxes were not clear, since they all contained "".

I tried to find an ExpectedConditions for the value to be equal to "" and not contain it but I could not.

I have seen people rewrite a wait method so they could customize it to what they want.  When I searched with google I could not find examples, though I am sure there are examples, as I have seen them before.  I just can't find them now.  Can anyone direct me to such an example (or just type one)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution

```
public static ExpectedCondition<WebElement> textInValue(final WebElement el) {
    return new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>() {
        @Override
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
            return el.getAttribute("value").equals("") ? el : null;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this

```
for (int ind = 0; ind < boxes.size(); ind++) {
    try {
        wt.until(textInValue(boxes.get(ind)));
    }
    catch (TimeoutException e) {
        // print message
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool.  Can I give it an error message to print?  Right now it is just
Timed out after 30 seconds waiting for lPage$1@6fd12330

Comment: I just put a try{} around it and caught a timeout exception and gave my own assert

Comment: Thank @guy I see we did the same thing at the same time ;-)

Comment: I am going to write something similar to wait for a value in class